# Integrating input from an external Bluetooth remote into Flutter app

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, assistive

I would like to handle events from a device like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CH8GD2GM) in my Flutter app. It is a bluetooth remote with a couple of buttons, that's paired at the system level and seems to use Assistive Touch (which I know nothing about). It doesn't seem to behave like a keyboard as I'm not receiving any event in a `KeyboardListener`. Does anybody have an idea of the protocol these use and how I could listen to it from within my Flutter app?